# Going live with ASP.NET vNext 1.0.0-rc1-update1

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core

We started to work on project during beta 7 & managed to implement most of functionality in version 1.0.0-rc1-update1. We are mostly using MVC for authenitication and web api to serve data. Most of the functionality is in client-side Angular.

Considering RC2 is now out, we don't have time to upgrade due functional deadline.

So the question is can we go-live with this version or MUST upgrade to RC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RC1 had a go-live license however since RC2 has been released RC1 is no longer supported. In other words, if you hit an issue no one will spend time investigating it. Given that the final 1.0 is planned to be shipped in the next few weeks and that changes between RC2 and RTW are minimal moving to RC2 is not a bad idea - it will be quick and easy to move from RC2 to the 1.0.0 final. Here are some resources that will help you migrate your RC1 to RC2:

- https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rc2.html
- https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1381